# macbook air のターミナルの立ち上げの文字

Tags: ruby, macos, shell, zsh

macbook のrubyの環境構築設定の際に
以下のような文章がついてしまいました。
初期値に戻すにはどうしたらいいですか？

```
Last login: Wed Sep 30 13:13:01 on ttys004
/Users/devmac1/.zshrc:1: no such file or directory: evalexport PATH="/Users/devmac1/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"\nexport RBENV_SHELL=zsh\nsource '/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec/../completions/rbenv.zsh'\ncommand rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null\nrbenv() {\n  local command\n  command="${1:-}"\n  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then\n    shift\n  fi\n\n  case "$command" in\n  rehash|shell)\n    eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;\n  *)\n    command rbenv "$command" "$@";;\n  esac\n}
/Users/devmac1/.zshrc:2: no such file or directory: evalexport PATH="/Users/devmac1/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"\nexport RBENV_SHELL=zsh\nsource '/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec/../completions/rbenv.zsh'\ncommand rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null\nrbenv() {\n  local command\n  command="${1:-}"\n  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then\n    shift\n  fi\n\n  case "$command" in\n  rehash|shell)\n    eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;\n  *)\n    command rbenv "$command" "$@";;\n  esac\n}
devmac1@DevMac1noMacBook-Air ~ %
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.zshrc` の1行目が `eval"$(rbenv init -)"` のようになっていてスペースが抜けているように見えるので、 `eval` と `"` の間にスペースを入れて `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` のようになるように修正すれば良さそうです。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。ターミナルにecho 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrcを記入してみましたがターミナル立ち上げ時、上記の文章が消えません。

Comment: 「'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc」だと元のファイルに追記するだけで、間違った記述は消せないのではないでしょうか。エディタで開いてみてどうなっているか確認してみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。PC初心者です。ターミナルにおける間違った記述の方法や修正方法が全くわかりません。よく理解していないので下手にさわれません。

Comment: open -e ~/.zshrc でテキストエディットが開きます。

Comment: 見れました。ありがとうございます。感謝。